# VueJS multiple toggle to open/hide element

Tags: vue.js, toggle

I am new to VueJS, I have multiple show/hide toggle to the elements separately.

here is the code:

```
<div id="card-1">
    <ul v-if="isOpen">
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>world</li>
    </ul>
    <a @click="toggle(1)">
        <span id="list-toggler-btn-1">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide all units
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="card-2">
    <ul v-if="isOpen">
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>mango</li>
    </ul>
    <a @click="toggle(2)">
        <span id="list-toggler-btn-2">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide all units
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

in Vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isOpen: 1
    },
    methods:{
        toggle: function(n){
            this.isOpen = this.isOpen == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                $("#list-toggler-btn-"+n).html(this.isOpen == 0 ?
                    '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> Show all units' : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide all units');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So far it is show/hide for both the `card-1` and `card-2` when the `toggle(n)` was clicked, I want it to be toggle only for itself element only, how can I do that in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

> TLDR; Ideally your `card` should be a separate component as such each component would maintain its own local state.

Having said that in your above example, you can do the following:

1. Do not mix jQuery with Vue code. You won't need it.
2. Think in terms of MVVM and not DOM manipulations.

Your code would be:

```
<div id="card-1">
    <ul v-if="!isHidden(1)">
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>world</li>
    </ul>
    <a @click="toggle(1)">
        <span id="list-toggler-btn-1">
            <template v-if="isHidden(1)">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> Show all units
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide all units
            </template>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="card-2">
    <ul v-if="!isHidden(2)">
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>mango</li>
    </ul>
    <a @click="toggle(2)">
        <span id="list-toggler-btn-2">
            <template v-if="isHidden(2)">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> Show all units
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide all units
            </template>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The JavaScript side code should be:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            // Maintain a list of hidden cards
            // Initially empty
            hiddenCards: []
        }
    },

    methods:{
        toggle(cardNumber) {

            // Assuming each card has unique cardNumber
            let hiddenCard = this.hiddenCards.find(cardNumber);

            if (hiddenCard) {
                // Item is hidden. Remove from hidden list and show it.
                this.hiddenCards = this.hiddenCards.filter((x) => x !== cardNumber);
            } else {
                // Hide the card now by adding to the list.
                this.hiddenCards = this.hiddenCards.concat(cardNumber);
            }
        },

        isHidden (cardNumber) {
            return this.hiddenCards.findIndex(cardNumber) > -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the following error after implement your codes -> `ReferenceError: isOpen is not defined`

Comment: @TheGrimmer silly mistake. Updated the code snippet.

Comment: @TheGrimmer Not sure why that would happen? Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: is not work,. it sayin "1 is not a function"